# How do I access a classes list from outside the class?

Tags: python, arrays, list, class

I tried to access a classes list from outside the class with `TestClass("other_variable").testList`, but it dosen't work, it returns `[]`.
This is my code:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, other_variable):
        self.other_variable = other_variable
        self.testList = []
      
    def appendToTestList(self, string):
        self.testList.append(string)
        print(self.testList) # This works, it prints the full list.
```

I wrote a function, hoping it would return the list, but it just returns the same thing (`[]`):

```
   def showTestList(self):
        return self.testList # Returns []
```

Comment: Did you call `appendToTestList` at all before calling `showTestList`?

Comment: Yes. Multiple times, and in appendToTestList it printed all of them.

Comment: Provide a full [mcve]

Comment: The expression in your first sentence creates a *new* instance of `TestClass`, unrelated to whatever instance you used to call `appendToTestList`.

Comment: You may not realize that `TestClass("other_variable").testList` creates a totally new instance of `TestClass`. So if you have a previous instance that you mutated, it won't affect class state or other instantations. Show your exact code as a [mcve] please.

Comment: The line of code you say you're using to access the list wont return anything other than its initial value, what code are you using  that uses `appendToTestList`?

Comment: But if I append to the list with ```TestClass("other_variable").appendToTestList("hey")```, and then call ```TestClass("other_variable").testList``` it still dosen't work.

Comment: Of course not: you never saved a reference to the object created by `TestClass("other_variable")` before calling `appendToTestList` on it. The object is created, it's attribute is appended to, and then it gets garbage-collected.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save a reference to your object first.

```
>>> x = TextClass("other_variable")
>>> x.appendToTestList("foo")
>>> x.appendToTestList("bar")
>>> x.testList
["foo", "bar"]
```